# Get order by date and status filters in magento 2 with rest api

Tags: orders, api, rest-api, order-grid, magento2.4.3

Get Orders details using rest API with filters status and date range in magneto 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If anyone need to get Orders details with filters status and date range in rest API please use this API endpoint**

> /rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=processing&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=from&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=2022-01-20%00:00:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=to&searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=2022-03-22%00:00:00